# My question is not listed

Tags: support, status-completed

I have created the following question:

[Name for rhetoric expressing a two contradictory meanings in one sentence?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/2561/name-for-rhetoric-expressing-a-two-contradictory-meanings-in-one-sentence)

But it does not appear in the question list.

Could you help please?

Answer (score 1):

This was a side-effect of our database migration. We had to rebuild a few services after it, so things were down for a while.

Should be all good now!